# JavaScript not validating form on second submit request

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have JavaScript code that will validate a form on the first submit request, but if the user then hits submit again, even though they have not rectified the form errors, the form will not process the validation function and will just submit.

I would like the validation function to be executed every time the user clicks on the submit button.

Thanks for any help, code below.
Martin

```
<form action="site.url" method="post" name="signup" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
    <label for="firstname"><span id="inactiveErrorFname">Please enter your first name<br></span>
        First name <strong title="Required" class="required">*</strong></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
    <label for="surname"><br><span id="inactiveErrorSname">Please enter your Surname<br></span>
        Surname</label><input type="text" name="lastName">  
    <label for="email">
        <span id="inactiveErrorEmail"><br>Please enter your Email address<br></span>
        Email address <strong title="Required" class="required">*</strong></label>
    <input type="text" name="emailAddress">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign up" />    
</form>

<script>

    function validateForm()
    {
        var x=document.forms["signup"]["firstName"].value;
        var y=document.forms["signup"]["lastName"].value;
        var z=document.forms["signup"]["emailAddress"].value;
        var atpos=z.indexOf("@");
        var fname;
        var sname;
        var email;

        /* Validate first name */
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("inactiveErrorFname").id = "activeErrorFname";
            fname = "true";
        }
        /* Validate Surname */
        if (y==null || y=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("inactiveErrorSname").id = "activeErrorSname";
            sname = "true";
        }
        /* Validate email */
        if (atpos<1)
        {
            document.getElementById("inactiveErrorEmail").id = "activeErrorEmail";
            email = "true";
        }
        if (fname=="true" || sname=="true" || email =="true")
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: why you are using ids for errors and why you are changing them? give them a class and then change the class.

Comment: so did your problem solved? if yes let me post an answer for that.

Comment: No problem still exists, just I call the error messages using a class instead of separate ids. I still have the problem with the validation function only executing once when the submit button is clicked twice.

Comment: please paste codes of your problem. and what you mean than'validation function only executing once when the submit button is clicked twice. '

Comment: Ha? The problem and the code are above, posted originally. Please read original question.

Comment: OK but what you mean than 'validation function only executing once when the submit button is clicked twice.' it works for first time and then it redirects without checking right? and please update the question with classes instead of ids.

Comment: Actually, using a class would activate all of the error messages. Using Ids means that when one condition is broken (e.g. the first name wasn't filled in) only that error message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is created by the fact you are changing the id's of certain elements. The first time you run your code, these statements are succesfully runned:

```
document.getElementById("inactiveErrorFname").id = "activeErrorFname";
document.getElementById("inactiveErrorSname").id = "activeErrorSname";
document.getElementById("inactiveErrorEmail").id = "activeErroremail";
```

The second time however the id's of these elements have changed, resulting in the fact that these statements call upon unexisting elements. This results in a javascript fatal error, with as consequence no `return false`. The second time your form will thus be submitted as it normally is. The solution to this problem is not changing the id's but changing the class of the error-labels. You can find an example in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4gvfan7/).

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="signup" onsubmit="return validateForm()"> 
    <label for="firstname">
      <span class="inactive" id="errorFname">Please enter your first name<br></span>
      First name <strong title="Required" class="required">*</strong>
    </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName"><br><br>

    <label for="surname">
      <span class="inactive" id="errorSname">Please enter your Surname<br></span>
      Surname
    </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName"><br><br>

    <label for="email">
        <span class="inactive" id="errorEmail"><br>Please enter your Email address<br></span>
        Email address <strong title="Required" class="required">*</strong>
    </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="emailAddress"><br><br>

    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign up" />    
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["signup"]["firstName"].value;
    var y=document.forms["signup"]["lastName"].value;
    var z=document.forms["signup"]["emailAddress"].value;
    var atpos=z.indexOf("@");
    var fname;
    var sname;
    var email;

    /* Validate first name */
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("errorFname").className = "active";
        fname = "true";
    }
    /* Validate Surname */
    if (y==null || y=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("errorSname").className = "active";
        sname = "true";
    }
    /* Validate email */
    if (atpos<1)
    {
        document.getElementById("errorEmail").className = "active";
        email = "true";
    }
    if (fname=="true" || sname=="true" || email =="true")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```